# Micronaut: API to retrieve @Named value for a bean built via @EachBean?

Tags: dependency-injection, micronaut

I have the following:

```
@Context
@EachProperty("some.property")
public class MyCfg {
    public MyCfg(@Parameter String name) {
        // ...
    }
}

@Factory
public class MyFactory {
    @Context
    @EachBean(MyCfg.class)
    public MyBean build(MyCfg cfg) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I read from the doc that instances of `MyBean` should inherit the `@Named` name from `MyCfg`, and in fact I can inject them (for example, as constructor parameters), `@Named("somename") MyBean myBean`.

If I retrieve their `BeanDefinition` programmaticaly via `BeanContext`, however, I don't seem to be able to have access to the instance name.

For example:

```
@EventListener
void onShutdown(ShutdownEvent event) {
    event.getSource().getBeanRegistrations(MyBean.class).forEach(br -> {
        log.info("Shutting down {}", br.getBeanDefinition().stringValue(Named.class)));
        br.getBean().close();
    });
}
```

prints `Shutting down Optional.empty`, while I expected it to print whatever the name was in `applicaiton.yml` under `some.property`.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to simply close the beans on shutdown, you can simply add `@Bean(preDestroy = "close")` to the factory method

Answer (score -1):

A bean registration would only exist once. You should be looking for bean definitions. `beanContext.getBeanDefinitions(...)`

Comment: Nope – the whole purpose of `@Named` is to have multiple beans of the same class (and discern between them). BTW the @EventListener I posted is what I use to close my connection pools (of which I have 2) and it works except for the "Optional.empty" in the log message

Comment: I'm aware of the purpose of @Named. What I suggested does work